# Can my office manager force me to lower my desk to sitting height at work?

Tags: ergonomics

I've been standing at my desk while I work. I have my monitors propped up on (admittedly silly looking) boxes and my keyboard and mouse too--bringing them to standing height.

My office manager (note, not my boss, my boss' boss, or anyone in my chain of command) wants my to resume sitting during work. I think this is unreasonable, but that's a matter of opinion.

I'm not really clear on what degree she can compel me to keep my computer equipment at a sitting height. I'd much prefer to stand due to health benefits, but it also seems like I should have the freedom to do so if I'm not bothering anybody--even if I didn't have a particularly good reason.

Does anyone have any ideas what my options are in this situation?

Comment: Have you asked your office manager why she wants you to sit?

Comment: This is also a question of ergonomics.

Answer (score 15):

Ask site safety and/or whoever deals with human factors and adaptive technology to give their opinion of your setup. I suspect the issue isn't your desire for a standing workstation (though not everyone is familiar with the idea and you may need to do some education before it's accepted) , but how you're achieving it. Before anything else, it has to be safe and stable to protect both employees and equipment.

Comment: Agreed. the monitors belong to the company not the employee.

Comment: Agreed, the concern here isn't so much that he is standing but they are afraid the equipment will topple over and someone will get hurt or killed and they will get sued. Or even if no one is hurt, the equiment falling over would be a cost to replace. If you want a standing desk, ask them to buy it or pay for it yourself. Don't use a hack to get it. BTW did you ask their permission before you moved their equipment to a potentially precarious position? If you didn't get permission first, there is no reason at all why they can't tell you no you can't do that. It is their equipment.

Answer (score 4):

Considering this person is not in the 'chain of command' it sounds like you have two choices.

Choice 1: Ignore them.

Choice 2: Go talk to your direct manager and ask them to step in on your side.

Personally, I'd take the initiative here and speak with my manager.  It's usually easier to get someone on your side when you are the first person to present arguments.

Comment: Office managers typically do have responsibilities that include office equiment. Ignoring this person is terrible advice.